# PCSAPI IBM Emulator programming on C#

Tags: c#, c

I need help in using for PCSAPI.dll for IBM Emulator programming.

A documentation is already provided in C. you can refer to this URL :

[PCSAPI Documentation IBM Emulator programming](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQ5Y_6.0.0/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/books/html/emulator_programming10.htm)

there is a function **pcsQuerySessionList** which is used to get the information about which session that is currently active and connected to the emulator. The function provided is in C, but I need to implement in C#.

this is the function provided from documentation :

```
ULONG PCSAPI_ENTRY pcsQuerySessionList(ULONG Count, SESSINFO *SessList);

typedef union _SESSNAME {   // Name field of SessInfo structure
  char ShortName;           // Short session ID (A-Z)
  ULONG Handle;             // Session handle
} SESSNAME;

typedef struct _SESSINFO {  // Description of a single session
  SESSNAME Name;            // Session name (ID or handle)
  ULONG    Status;          // Session status (PCS_SESSION_* bit flags)
} SESSINFO;
```

and this the detail about the pcsQuerySessionList :

```
Function Type
ULONG WINAPI pcsQuerySessionList(ULONG Count, SESSINFO *SessionList)

Parameter Type and Description
ULONG Count
- Number of elements in the SessionList array
SESSINFO *SessionList
- Pointer to an array of SESSINFO structures as defined in PCSAPI.H
```

and this is an example of using the function :

```
ULONG      NumSessions, i;  // Session counters
SESSINFO   *SessList;       // Array of session information structures
// Find out number of sessions that exist
NumSessions = pcsQuerySessionList (0,NULL);
if (NumSessions == 0) {
   printf("There are no sessions.");
   exit;
}

// Allocate array large enough for all sessions
SessList = (SESSINFO *)malloc(NumSessions * sizeof(SESSINFO));
memset(SessList, 0x00, NumSessions * sizeof(SESSINFO));

// Now read actual session info
pcsQuerySessionList(NumSessions, SessList);

for (i=0; i<NumSessions; i++) {
   if ((SessList[i].Status & PCS_SESSION_STARTED) &&
       (SessList[i].Status & PCS_SESSION_ONLINE))  {

      printf("Session %c is started and connected.",
        SessList[i].Name.ShortName);
   }
}

exit;
```

I already try to implement it to C#. you can see it in the code below :

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("PCSAPI32.dll")]
    public static extern int pcsQuerySessionList(out int sessionCount, out SESSINFO sessionInfo);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SESSNAME
    {
        char ShortName;
        ulong Handle;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SESSINFO
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
        SESSNAME Name;
        ulong Status;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int sessCount = 0;
            SESSINFO structSESSINFO;
            sessCount = pcsQuerySessionList(out sessCount, out structSESSINFO);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

from implementation above, I succeeded in getting the return value (SESSINFO). however, I need to obtain all the active session information when the emulator is running multiple sessions, while my code only returns the first active session. when I tried to parse SESSINFO into an array I got an access violation error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in PCSAPI.exe. 
>   Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

please help me solving this problem. any help would be much appreciated.

--EDIT--

thanks for the suggestion. however, i already tried what you suggested and the same error still occured.

```
[DllImport("PCSAPI32.dll")]
public static extern int pcsQuerySessionList(out int sessionCount, ref SESSINFO[] sessionInfo);

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int sessCount = 0;
        SESSINFO[] structSESSINFO = new SESSINFO[sessCount];
        sessCount = pcsQuerySessionList(out sessCount, ref structSESSINFO);
        structSESSINFO = new SESSINFO[sessCount];
        pcsQuerySessionList(out sessCount, ref structSESSINFO);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

in addition, i already get sessCount value (not using array), and i already get structSESSINFO value too but can't get SESSINFO with array method (multiple session). it's always get same error.

--Edit again--

this is the code :

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("PCSAPI32.dll")]
    public static extern int pcsQuerySessionList(int sessionCount, SESSINFO[] sessionInfo);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SESSNAME
    {
        char ShortName;
        ulong Handle;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SESSINFO
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
        SESSNAME Name;
        ulong Status;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int returnVal;
            SESSINFO[] structSESSINFO = null;
            returnVal = pcsQuerySessionList(0, structSESSINFO);
            structSESSINFO = new SESSINFO[returnVal];
            pcsQuerySessionList(returnVal, structSESSINFO);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

i already tried rs232 suggestion. the code above run without error. i got the returnVal but structSESSINFO is empty.

thanks again for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Method signature

```
ULONG PCSAPI_ENTRY pcsQuerySessionList(ULONG Count, SESSINFO *SessList);
```

and its description you've provided both indicate that the function expects you to provide it with **already allocated** array of SESSINFO structures: SessList parameter should contain a reference to that array and Count paramter indicates an amount of elements in that array. You cannot declare the funciton's parameters as 'out' and expect them to be set by the function, it is your responsibility to allocate an array and to pass a correct number of items in that array, only then the function will fill the values into the array.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. however, i already tried what you suggested and the same error still occured.

Comment: 1. sessCount should not be 'out'. 2. structSESSINFO should not be 'ref'. 3. when you first call pcsQuerySessionList, pass null as the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks for helping. how do we get returns value from SESSINFO if we are not using out or ref ? i already tried using null value on SESSINFO and SESSINFO value was still null.

Comment: When you use it with 'ref' you effectively pass SESSINFO** to pcsQuerySessionList. SESSINFO[] is a reference type - that's why you should use neither "out" nor "ref" with SessList.

Comment: "i already tried using null value on SESSINFO and SESSINFO value was still null" - Once again: use null when you do the **first** call. Use an initialized array (without any 'out' or 'ref' modifiers) for the **second** call.

Comment: thanks again for helping. i already tried your suggestion. you can see my edited code in the main question. please help :(

Comment: Oh, that's great - we're getting somewhere! :) When you write "i got the returnVal but structSESSINFO is empty.", do you mean that it happens after the first call or after the second? It should be empty after the first call, btw. What is the value of returnVal, which you get from the first call? Could you please get the result of the second call too?

Comment: nothing change for structSESSINFO after i execute the function. After first call it's still null, and nothing change after the second call. It's always have same value (empty). And for returnVal the value is depends on how many session active in emulator. And in this case returnVal always give a correct return.

Comment: I've just seen that you have SESSNAME defined as struct. This is not correct since in C++ it is a union. The library writes a four-byte element there, but you interpret it as a six-byte one. For simplicity, I would recommend to try to replace it with another ulong in SESSINFO, so SESSINFO contains only two ulong fields: ulong Handle and ulong Status

Comment: I already tried your suggestions. Change SESSINFO into 2 two field, ulong handle and ulong status, but it's still same like before. still got null on first call and 0 value (empty) on the second call.

Comment: "still got null on first call" - this is the expected behaviour. The function does not and can not reallocate your array. The first call is there to determine the amount of sessions and it seems to do that perfectly as you say it returns the proper amount of current sessions. "and 0 value (empty) on the second call" - what do you mean by that? which variable's value is 0 after the second call?

Comment: that SESSINFO variable after i assign an array size and execute the second call the value of Handle and Status are 0. Are we expected the detail of session info return value on SESSINFO struct ? how we get return value on SESSINFO struct we not using any ref or out ? The problem is i can't get any detail information about session active on emulator, like session name, session status, etc.

Comment: "how we get return value on SESSINFO struct we not using any ref or out ?" - pcsQuerySessionList assepts SESSINFO* as the second parameter. You have SESSINFO[], which is a reference-type variable, effectively SESSINFO*. When you pass it as a parameter, you do not want the function to alter the variable's value (which is a reference to the memory location where you actual data is stored), but to access that memory and change data in there. "out" is not needed since you don't get the reference from the function. "ref" is not needed as you don't need to modify the reference.

Comment: This reference/value thing is a pretty wast topic, I doubt it is possible to explain it in a couple of SO comments :)

Comment: I do not think I could help you any further here. I was able to resolve your original question: to fix your call parameters so they get accepted by your unmanaged library. However, since I am not familiar with PCSAPI emulator itself, I can't tell you why it does not return you the information you need, that's more up to you to find it out. GL.